# powershell session connection cmdlets not work when executed in function

Tags: powershell, office365

I get connected to Exchange in the cloud by issuing a series of powershell commands:

```
$credential = new-object -typename ... -argumentList ...
$session = New-PSSession -configurationName ... -connectionUri ... -credential $credential ...
Import-PSSession $session ...
```

I can then issue commands to do things I need to do, e.g.,

```
get-mailbox | ? {$_.aliast -like "*[.]*"} | select alias

alias
-----
john.public
jane.doe
...
```

However, the cmdlets for obtaining a PSSession are long, and typing them is error-prone even if I could manage to memorize them correctly.  So I saved all the three long command lines verbatim in a function:

```
function get-365session() {
   $credential = new-object -typename ... -argumentList ...
   $session = New-PSSession -configurationName ... -connectionUri ... -credential $credential ...
   Import-PSSession $session ...
}
```

But it does not work out as expected:

```
PS> get-365session
ModuleType Version    Name             ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----             -----------------
...

PS> get-mailbox 
get-mailbox: The term 'get-mailbox' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlt, function, script file, ....
```

I thought the session was obtained but was gone with the function's "sub-shell" as soon as the function has completed its run.  I therefore tried

```
PS> . get-365session
```

But it was to no avail.

Hope there is a way and someone can help me out.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the session in the current scope using `Import-Module` with the `-Global` flag.

Your `Import-PSSession` line should look like

`Import-Module (Import-PSSession $session365 -AllowClobber) -Global`

Here is a working example:

```
function Connect-O365{
    $o365cred = Get-Credential username@domain.onmicrosoft.com
    $session365 = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/" -Credential $o365cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection 
    Import-Module (Import-PSSession $session365 -AllowClobber) -Global
}

Connect-O365
```

**Reference**

[This technet forum thread from 2012](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/529bd0ef-5e88-4808-a5ac-dc07ca8660f3/importpssession-is-not-importing-cmdlets-when-used-in-a-custom-module?forum=winserverpowershell)

Comment: Thank you Sage Pourpre.  It works exactly what wanted.  Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Bender the Greatest for sharing that trick.  I will try it out when I have time to turn around.

Answer (score 0):

Local functions and variables are not available in other sessions. However, you can use the [following trick](http://duffney.io/RunLocalFunctionsRemotely) to specify your function as a script block:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock ${Function:My-FunctionName}
```

The article I linked to above goes into more detail about more advanced use-cases for this, but as your script doesn't seem to require any parameters. Do note that this requires the use of `Invoke-Command` to run the code in the other session, *from the session where the function is defined*, so I'm not sure how, if you could, get the function body if you have already done `Enter-PSSession` and are currently in the remote session.